# Structuring report package dependencies

Tags: managed-package, reporting, package, appexchange, dashboard

I'm working on a managed package that contains several reports and dashboards, as well as custom fields on standard objects that power those reports.

From what I know, reports and dashboards cannot be "upgraded", so if I ever want to tweak my reports or add new ones, I would need to create a new package.  Does this sound right?

On the other hand, my set of custom fields that the reports depend on *are* things I want to manage and add to by upgrading the package.

If so, what's the best practice for organizing my report packages?  Here are some options

```
[Reports and custom fields] (add new reports by upgrading this package with new reports)

                                 /--- [Report extension package 1]
[Base package with custom fields]---- [Report extension package 2]
                                 \--- [Report extension package 3]

                                   /--- [Report extension package 2]
[Initial reports and custom fields]---- [Report extension package 3]
                                   \--- [Report extension package 4]
```

Thanks!